# FinancialData price adjustments no longer work?

Tags: curated-data, finance

#### TL;DR

The following properties of `FinancialData` appear to no longer work:

```
Change
Close
FractionalChange
High
Low
Open
OHLC
OHLCV
Return
```

#### More info

According to the Documentation page for `FinancialData`:

> For historical data, properties such as "High", "Low", "Close" are adjusted for stock splits, dividends and related changes.

As best I can interpret this, if you want an adjusted close price, use `Close`, and for the unadjusted price, use `RawClose`.

However, it appears prices are not adjusted. For example, for GE (and every other stock I've tested so far), the `Close` and `RawClose` prices are exactly the same:

```
FinancialData["NYSE:GE", "Close", {"Dec 20, 2002", "Dec 24, 2002"}, "Values"]
FinancialData["NYSE:GE", "RawClose", {"Dec 20, 2002", "Dec 24, 2002"}, "Values"]
(*{25.95, 25.73, 25.33}*)
(*{25.95, 25.73, 25.33}*)
```

Yahoo Finance historical data shows that the `RawClose` is correct, but the `Close` is wrong:

[image]

The same behavior applies to `Open` vs `RawOpen`, `High` vs `RawHigh`, `Low` vs `RawLow`, and `Range` vs `RawRange`... the raw price and the non-raw price are the same.

Similarly, quantities derived from these adjusted properties, like `OHLC`, `OHLCV`, `Change`, `FractionalChange`, and `Return` are also broken, as a couple quick calculations will confirm.

I've held off on adding the "bug" tag since I'd like another set of eyes, but this appears to be a significant regression affecting most of `FinancialData`'s properties. This is on V10.2, but gwr has also observed it on V11.2 so I suspect it is version-independent.